# Another phrase for "difficult task is set for somebody"

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

All I can formulate is the phrase "difficult task is set for somebody". I feel it sounds clumsy. What is a natural phrase to convey the following meaning?

> A difficult task is set for the government in the near future, on the one hand - to keep the budget, on the other hand - to ensure support for businesses in entrepreneurial and investment activities.

Comment: "sb." isn't an abbreviation for "somebody" -- it doesn't have an abbreviation.

Comment: @Jason That's not true.  Perhaps you mean to say it isn't *usually* abbreviated that way, which is true, but it's common enough in (for example) certain dictionaries.  It's a mistake to claim the abbreviation doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

One phrase sometimes used is *herculean task*, a metaphor based on the [labors of Hercules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labours_of_Hercules).

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Herculean) defines *herculian* as:

> **herculean** (*adj.*)  requiring tremendous effort, strength, etc: *a herculean task*.

Although Hercules accomplished his tasks long ago, the phrase is still in vogue. You can find [many instances of it in contemporary news articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22will%20be%20a%20herculean%20task%22), like this one:

> As genotyping and companion diagnostics are used more widely in clinical care, determining the ‘best’ therapy for a given patient will become a massively complex task. Considering all the combinations of genomic risk factors, drug interactions and phenotypic influences, selecting the most appropriate therapy **will be a Herculean task**. ([Source](http://genokey.com/enabling-smart-medical-devices/))

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say it as:

> In the future it will be difficult for the government to set the
>   budget and to ensure support for businesses in entrepreneurial and
>   investment activities.

Or,

> In the **near future** it will be a **difficult task/challenge** for
>   the government to set the budget and to ensure support for businesses
>   in entrepreneurial and investment activities.

Comment: Thanks. But I desperately need to use something like 'task', 'goal' or 'challenge' as well as 'in perspective' or 'in the near future'.

Comment: @Humbulani I edited my answer. You can see it above.

Answer (score 0):

> A difficult task is set for the government in the near future, on the one hand - to keep the budget, on the other hand - to ensure support for businesses in entrepreneurial and investment activities.

My two cents:

> **In the days ahead**, the government **will face the hard task** of keeping the budget untouched on the one hand and ensuring support to businesses engaged in entrepreneurial and investment activities on the other.

Humbulani, it's good excercise to look in thesaura and idiom collections online for alternatives to particular words and expressions and then reformulate your sentence in several different ways. Or, just type out related expression you know in a separate text editor window, a kind of brainstorm session:

> **"on the one \ other hand"**
>   Balancing act,  tip the scales, double-edged sword, keep the balance, to balance one against the other, to combine one and the other, to blend,  to walk the line,
>   It will be the hard balancing act to..
>   The Government will be faced with..
>   **"In the near future"**
>   In the perspective, in the days ahead, in the weaks ahead, in the near-term perspective,
>   The Government's near-term task will be tough: to keep the budget while ensuring that the businesses engaged in entrepreneurial and investment activities are provided with support.

Answer (score 0):

A more informal, colloquial variation is *(having their) work cut out for them*